What package(s) do I need to add BroadcastReceiver to my MAUI .NET 8 C# app?
I'm writing a C# MAUI app in .Net 8, and I'm having trouble adding a BroadcastReceiver because it apparently doesn't exist in any of the packages I have. I haven't been able to find the right package that would give me this.
Here are my current packages:
    <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Maui" Version="9.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Mvvm" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications" Version="7.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="8.0.40" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility" Version="8.0.40" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="8.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>

Here's the new class I'm trying to create.
namespace RemindMe.Services;

[BroadcastReceiver( Enabled = true )]
public class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
}

When I pick "Quick Actions and Refactorings," it doesn't show me the option to use any namespace, which usually means I don't have a package that contains the class.
Can someone tell me what package to use? I've looked all over and didn't find one. I read that Mono.Android was what I needed, but I can't find that on Nuget.
Thank you

My project can directly use the BroadcastReceiver class without adding another package. Did you select YourProject(net8.0-andorid) as the platform selection in the upper left corner of VS?

Yes. It's there in the upper-left corner of the source file's tab. But also, I opened the project to check that, saw that it was there, then discovered that I could tell it to use Android.Content, which never happened before. You know, sometimes VS just doesn't want to work until suddenly it does. I don't know if I had done something yesterday that triggered it to get set right or if it just fixed itself.
But thanks! This told me where the problem lay, and I appreciate that.

I am very glad to help you. I summarized the answer to this question:
In all versions of MAUI, Android Tools (JDK 11
and Android SDK 34) are automatically supported, so you can use the BroadcastReceiver class directly in the .cs file.
Since this class does not exist on the iOS and Windows platforms, you need to select YourProject(net8.0-andorid) as the platform selection in the upper left corner of VS, or use the invoke plateform code to use this class.

user24884869's comment did the trick! I had to select the right project type for the source code.
